# How to change an ImageView without loosing format

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I will like to change an `ImageView` when a `boolean` turns "true". In this case I want to change from "normal stars" to "yellow stars" in case that users takes a certain experience.
I actually have a similar code using `ImageButton`. This change the the Image when button is pressed, but then back to the original.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_normal"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" />
</selector>
```

and

```
<ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_48sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_48sdp"
                            android:id="@+id/star"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star/>
```

How is possible to replace an `ImageView` without loosing format in layout conserving position, dp.??? Not using buttons, user should not change the image by his own.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the size? The images you are trying to switch are of a different size? If so just specify maxWidth and maxHeight.

Comment: because in this way the  images can be seen with the same proportions in differents screens, like here https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of selectors so i would do it programmatically like so:

```
if (boolean){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_yellow);
}
```

To avoid resizing specify your ImageView xml like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/star_normal"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="48dp"/>
```